# How separate data obtained from server by unique separator?

Tags: android, database, split, server, separator

I want to ask if there's some way to split data obtained from server by some unique separator.

**Here is an example:**

I use AsyncTask to send data to server and then I use echo command for sending those back to my application and in onPostExecute I split these data to needed result.

So let's say, that I want to get from server data for **Name** and **Surname**, so echo command on server will look like this: `echo $name."&".$surname;`

And then in onPostExecute I will split this data by **"&"** separator, but problem occurs when user writes to name or surname my separator **"&"** which I am using for split.

**How can I avoid this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using JSON. It's a life saver for sending data.
Android has native JSON support using a JSONObject.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

It essentially provides a formatter and parser for information placed within the object that are then accessible via keywords.

To write a json:

```
public String writeJSON() {
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
  try {
    object.put("name", "John");
    object.put("surname", "Doe");
    return object.toString();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

This will return a string that looks like:

```
{"name":"John","surname":"Doe"}
```

To read:

```
public void readJSON(String jsonString){
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        String name = object.getString("name");
        String surname = object.getString("surname");
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the character you are using to separate the different entries in the content you are transmitting [1]. For example:
`My\&FirstName&MySecondName` (In this case \ is used as escape character)

However, you don't need to reinvent all this stuff. There are several formats that you could use to transmit your data:

- json
- xml
- csv

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I have to accept Helix's one.